# Can I install Java and turn it off?

Tags: windows-7, installation, java

#### Question:

**Can I turn Java on and off so that it is only active when I consciously choose it  ?**

---

**Background** (Long version of story if needed)...

Hard drive failed.

Put a new one on.

Decided against a restore from my backup drive, and opted instead to reinstall only those things that I knew I wanted right then and there.

There is a freebie app that I would like to download. I clicked on the *[Download]* button on the web page. I get a file called *grapher.jnlp*

Wondering why nothing happened, I looked again and saw this on the webpage...

*Note: This program requires Java 6.0 or higher. If the program did not start after double-clicking on it then you must download Java from: http://www.java.com/getjava/*

Honestly, up until this one app, life has been pretty nice without Java.

The value of the grapher app is high enough to induce me to install Java again.

Life without Java has been nice enough to make me want to not do that.

With these two or three factors in place, it would be so nice if I could have Java when I have to have it, and put it away when I don't want it around.

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Sure through the Java control panel

Comment: Can you point me to a link that explains more about it ?

Comment: Go to control panel, double click java. The rest is self explainatory.

Comment: @LPChip  Thank you for a direct and helpful answer

Comment: @User.1 - More about a control panel?  No; I can't supply a link that explains the Java Control Panel its self explanatory.

Comment: [How do I enable Java through the Control Panel?](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/enable_panel.xml) and [How do I disable Java in my web browser?](http://java.com/en/download/help/disable_browser.xml)